# Pass a service response to rest operator arguments in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameter-passing

I have a 3rd party application I'm integrating with, and I need to pass a collection of objects, to a method that's expecting an argument set as a rest operator:

Signature of the method:

```
loadTranslations(...args: Locale[]): void
```

Currently, I have to hard code these locales, and pass them through as parameters (locale1, locale2, locale3), etc. However, I want to return these from a service, but I'm having no luck.

Take into account, I cannot update the method in the application we're integrating with.

My service:

```
localeForPage(): any {
    return [{
        lang: 'en',
        data: {
            _heading: {
                Title: 'Page Heading',
                Description: 'Testing the page localization'
            }
        }
    }, {
        lang: 'tr',
        data: {
            _heading: {
                title: 'Blah Blah Blah',
                description: 'Nah nah blah blah v1.02.2019'
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I really don't want to split the array into arguments before sending them through to the method, however, if that is my only option, then so be it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the issue. Also, where is the third party application located? Are you performing an HTTP call? Is it a third party library included locally?

Comment: @briosheje nevermind, i clearly don't know how the rest operator in javascript works :$. i need to explicitly note that the incoming array should be spread (...service.localeForPage())

Comment: Hmm fine, however, I'm wondering.. if that's a REST service.. How is it expecting to be spreaded? In any case, you can just edit your signature to return the spread array instead (`return ...[{`)